# Using requests in python 3.x to search for a keword

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a script that is supposed to make a query on the following website. https://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/.

```
import requests
keyword = "something"
body = {"query":keyword}
page = requests.post('https://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/', data=body)        
print(page3.content)
```

This just returns the webpages html code as it is, without the keyword search. Any ideas on what am i doing wrong? Also is there a way to filter out only the links that the search reutrns?

The way i wanted to do it was to go through the html code and isolate all strings that start that look like this:
https://example-link.com

I think my main issue is that i need to pull up "advanced search" before i search for my keyword. That seems to be messing things up for me. I am not entirely sure as i've never done this before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why `{"query":keyword}`?

Comment: @Finomnis I'm not used to working with requests, so i was assuming that is where i need to specify the string that has to be looked up.

Comment: It has nothing to do with requests, it is basic html. `<input type="text" style="width:380" name="search_text" id="search_text" maxlength="256" value="" tabindex="1">` clearly specifies that the tag for post is `"search_text"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got the `"query"` tag, but the correct tag for searches on this website is `"search_text"`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

keyword = "something"
body = {"search_text":keyword}
page = requests.post('https://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/', data=body)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a.has_attr('class') and 'filing' in a['class']:
        print(a['href'])
```

```
javascript:opennew('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/<...>/<...>.htm','<...>','');
javascript:opennew('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/<...>/<...>.htm','<...>','');
javascript:opennew('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/<...>/<...>.htm','<...>','');
javascript:opennew('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/<...>/<...>.htm','<...>','');
```

Comment: I have corrected my code, however the result remains same.

Comment: Remains the same how? I do now get the full list of results. As html, of course, but the table with the links is there.

Comment: The results don't match with what i see on the website. It i should have 5 keywords that match however my script is counting 1. Is there anyway to open the page that is generated?

Comment: Sure, store it as html-file and open it with your browser.

Comment: Thanks! i thought of that after i left this comment. Seems to work perfectly fine. Thanks!